# How should I match a pattern in Scala?

Tags: scala

I need to do a pattern in Scala, this is a code:

```
object Wykonaj{

val doctype = DocType("html", PublicID("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN","http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"), Nil)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val theUrl = "http://axv.pl/rss/waluty.php"
  val xmlString = Source.fromURL(new URL(theUrl)).mkString
  val xml = XML.loadString(xmlString)
   val zawartosc= (xml \\ "description")
 val pattern="""<descrition> </descrition>""".r 
 for(a <-zawartosc) yield a match{
 case pattern=>println(pattern) 
 }
     }     
}
```

The problem is, I need to do `val pattern=any` pattern, to get from

```
<description><![CDATA[ <img src="http://youbookmarks.com/waluty/pic/waluty/AUD.gif"> dolar australijski 1AUD | 2,7778 | 210/A/NBP/2010 ]]> </description>
```

only it dolar australijski 1AUD | 2,7778 | 210/A/NBP/2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

//...

val Pattern = new Regex(""".*; ([^<]*) </description>""")

//...

for(a <-zawartosc) yield a match {
  case Pattern(p) => println(p)
}
```

It's a bit of a kludge (I don't use REs with Scala very often), but it seems to work.  The CDATA is stringified as `&gt;` entities, so the RE tries to find text after a semicolon and before a closing description tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
val zawartosc = (xml \\ "description")
val pattern = """.*(dolar australijski.*)""".r 
val allMatches = (for (a <- zawartosc; text = a.text) yield {text}) collect { 
   case pattern(value) => value }
val result = allMatches.headOption // or .head
```

This is mostly a matter of using the right regular expression. In this case you want to match the string that contains `dolar australijski`. It has to allow for extra characters before `dolar`. So use `.*`. Then use the parens to mark the start and end of what you need. Refer to the [Java api for the full doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

With respect to the `for` comprehension, I convert the XML element into text before doing the match and then collect the ones that match the pattern by using the `collect` method. Then the desired result should be the first and only element.